# Python Timed-Script

Tags: python

How do I have a python script run everyday at a set-time. Say exactly at 2:00 P.M. every day.

Is there a way to have it run exactly twice a day?

Not really sure where to start with this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: in linux/unix you can use cron

Comment: use cron if that is available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't reinvent and use functionality existing for decades on any system: **cron**

Apart from that: PyPI lists a bunch of cron-related or cron-similar packages:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=cron&submit=search

In addition: Python provides a dedicated 'sched' module:

http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html