# How to run a python script at a specific time(s)

Tags: python

I'd like to write a simple python script for doing a specific job. I'm getting some time and link information from a web site.

```
times=
[
('17.04.2011', '06:41:44', 'abc.php?xxx'),
('17.04.2011', '07:21:31', 'abc.php?yyy'),
('17.04.2011', '07:33:04', 'abc.php?zzz'),
('17.04.2011', '07:41:23', 'abc.php?www'),]
```

What is the best way to click these links at the right time? Do I need to calculate the time interval between the current and the one in list and sleep for a while?

I'm really stuck at this point and open to any ideas which could be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Timed-Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657429/python-timed-script)

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657429/python-timed-script/5658088#5658088

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at Python's [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) module.

Answer (score 8):

you can use schedule module and it is easy to use and will satisfy your requirement.

you can try something like this.

```
import datetime, schedule, requests, time

TIME = [('17.04.2011', '06:41:44', 'abc.php?xxx'),
    ('17.04.2011', '07:21:31', 'abc.php?yyy'),
    ('17.04.2011', '07:33:04', 'abc.php?zzz'),
    ('17.04.2011', '07:41:23', 'abc.php?www')]

def job():
    global TIME
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
    for i in TIME:
        runTime = i[0] + " " + i[1]
        if i and date == str(runTime):
            requests.get(str(i[2]))

schedule.every(0.01).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have use request module and get method to call those URL. You can write whichever methods suits you.

Comment: This was a great example!

Comment: btw you don't need `global TIME` because `TIME` is not getting reassigned in the code.

Answer (score 3):

This may help: [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python) It is about cron-like scheduling in Python. And yes, it is based on sleeps.

Answer (score 1):

I finally made and used this.

```
import time,datetime

def sleep_till_future(f_minute):
    """The function takes the current time, and calculates for how many seconds should sleep until a user provided minute in the future."""       
    t = datetime.datetime.today()
    future = datetime.datetime(t.year,t.month,t.day,t.hour,f_minute)
    if future.minute <= t.minute:
        print("ERROR! Enter a valid minute in the future.")
    else:
        print "Current time: " + str(t.hour)+":"+str(t.minute)
        print "Sleep until : " + str(future.hour)+":"+str(future.minute)
        seconds_till_future = (future-t).seconds
        time.sleep( seconds_till_future )
        print "I slept for "+str(seconds_till_future)+" seconds!"
```