# Create a bot to click a download button at 9:00am, 10:00am, etc. using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**My Code**

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://www.barchart.com/options/most-active/etfs?viewName=main'))

downloadExcel = browser.find_element_by_class('bc-glyph-download')
downloadExcel.click()
```

I need to create a bot that will press the download button (class="bc-glyph-download") on the website: [wwww.barchart.com](https://www.barchart.com/options/most-active/etfs?viewName=main) every hour at 9, 10, 11, etc central time. This should download a saved CSV excel sheet on my desktop.

There were no stackoverflow articles on how to possibly do this that I saw. If this is going to be "hard", I may have to manually collect the excel sheets myself.

Comment: So you want to run the script you've shown on the hour? `cron` probably suits your needs https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677853/how-to-run-a-python-script-at-a-specific-times

Comment: I need to download the current ETF excel data every hour at 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, and 3. This will automatically run automatically for several weeks, possibly months.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a very easy way to do this. You can use the `Advanced Python Scheduler` module. Here is how:

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://www.barchart.com/options/most-active/etfs?viewName=main'))

def tick():
    downloadExcel = browser.find_element_by_class('bc-glyph-download')
    downloadExcel.click()
    print("Task completed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', hours=1)

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```